# multiple command execution

Tags: inno-setup, postgresql

I have created a installer with innosetup and i wanna use it to create a postgresql database using psql.exe .
I call the psql.exe with this line of code :

Filename: "{app}\PostgreSQL\bin\psql.exe"; Parameters: "-W postgres";

The problem is that psql ask for user password and there is no option to pass it in one call .

Is it possible to simulate the "Enter" key and add the password just after ?
If there is another solution let me know please.

Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [`PGPASSWORD` environment variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html):

> `PGPASSWORD` behaves the same as the password connection parameter. Use of this environment variable is not recommended for security reasons, as some operating systems allow non-root users to see process environment variables via ps; instead consider using the `~/.pgpass` file.

As mentioned, there is also the [password file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) but the environment variable would probably be fine for an installer. In either case you'd drop the `-W` switch.

You could also build a special purpose tool to talk to PostgreSQL directly rather than go through `psql.exe`.

Comment: That environment variable can also be set for Inno (and subsequant child processes) by using the [Win32 SetEnvironmentVariable() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686206(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Deanna: Thanks, that's useful information. I'm a lot more familiar with PostgreSQL than Inno.

Comment: how can i use the PGPASSWORD to login ?

Comment: @isoman: If you set the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable to the password before running `psql.exe postgres` (no `-W` needed), it should work.